# Exporting a complete Git repository at a certain point of time

Tags: git

I have a Git repository with a couple of branches and tons of commits. I'd like to export the complete history of all branches, but exactly as it was at a certain date.

I tried reading around the "git bundle" command, but it only seems to export single branches and it seems to be hard/impossible to specify a path-ref that will exclude commits after a certain point of time.

In a way, I'd just like to turn back the clock to get the exact state as if I would look at the repository on the server X days/weeks/months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. Do in a copy of the repo, just in case:

1. For each branch (including master), checkout the branch and do a hard reset to the date you want
2. Do garbage collection
3. Do a clone of the repository, and pull each of the branches you want.

I know that, if you have lots of branches this can be time consuming but you can create a script to do the checkouts and pulls.

The clone will include only the commits up to the heads of each branch and will get rid of the dangling commits (the garbage collection might do it too).

--dmg

Comment: This was the plan I had in mind. If there's no better solution, then I guess that's what I'll have to do. Thank you!